# JavaVM Windows 7 64bit - JFileChooser() not showing dialog box

Tags: java, windows-7, 64-bit, jfilechooser

I am trying to create a simple console based java application, which requires users to select files from their local filesystem.

The console prompts the user to select one of the available options and then switches on the input given.

```
public Client() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    printuseroptions();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    char userdecision = br.readLine().charAt(0);

    System.out.println(userdecision);

    switch(userdecision){
        case '1':
            System.out.println("Which file would you like to open?");
            openfile(br.readLine());
            break;
        case '2':
            System.out.println("Which file would you like to close?");
            closefile(br.readLine());
            break;
        }

private boolean openfile(String path){
    System.out.println("openfile("+path+")");
    return false;
}

private boolean closefile(String path){
    System.out.println("closefile("+path+")");
    new JFileChooser().showOpenDialog(null);
    return false;
}
```

No matter what I do, the JFileChooser pop up box will not open. No error is shown on the console, but a debug step-through shows the following error:

> Blockquote
>   Thread [main] (Suspended)
>       ClassNotFoundException(Throwable).(String, Throwable) line: 217
>       ClassNotFoundException(Exception).(String, Throwable) line: not available 
>       ClassNotFoundException.(String) line: not available
>       URLClassLoader$1.run() line: not available
>       AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction, AccessControlContext) line: not available [native method]
>       Launcher$ExtClassLoader(URLClassLoader).findClass(String) line: not available
>       Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(String) line: not available
>       Launcher$ExtClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
>       Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available 
>       Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(String, boolean) line: not available
>       Launcher$AppClassLoader(ClassLoader).loadClass(String) line: not available
>       ResourceBundle$RBClassLoader.loadClass(String) line: not available
>       CoreResourceBundleControl(ResourceBundle$Control).newBundle(String, Locale, String, ClassLoader, boolean) line: not available
>       ResourceBundle.loadBundle(CacheKey, List, Control, boolean) line: not available 
>       ResourceBundle.findBundle(CacheKey, List, List, int, Control, ResourceBundle) line: not available
>       ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(String, Locale, ClassLoader, ResourceBundle$Control) line: not available
>       ResourceBundle.getBundle(String, ResourceBundle$Control) line: not available
>       Toolkit$3.run() line: not available 
>       AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction) line: not available [native method]
>       Toolkit.() line: not available
>       Component.() line: not available
>       Client.closefile() line: 90 
>       Client.() line: 60
>       Client.main(String[]) line: 36

The same code runs perfectly on a Linux 32 bit machine, so I suspect the problem is Windows related.

The code below runs as expected on both Windows and Linux so I suspect might be due to the different ways in while console input is handled in Windows vs Linux (CR LF).

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JFileChooser().showOpenDialog(null);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just as new here as I am. ;)  Let's see if I can help.

I made changes to your code to get it to compile, and ran it on a Windows Server 2003 x64 machine, and didn't see any problems - the file chooser dialog opens.

I suggest two things you can do to eliminate other possibilities:

1) Ensure the system's native look & feel is set. Set your look & feel to the system default by using this when your program starts: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`

2) Ensure you only construct and open your `JFileChooserDialog`, and all other Swing components, inside the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).  If you know the current thread is the main thread or some other worker thread (and I assume it is because you're taking console input), you need to call `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)` for correct execution.

Good luck with that.

Comment: Hi,

The next day after posting the original question I figured out what the problem was.

There was no problem!

The dialog box was opening, but it was opening behind the IDE, but no java icon was being shown in the taskbar so I never realised that it was actually opening.

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes - I find that happens pretty often in Eclipse, especially with Dialogs and splash screens, which don't have taskbar icons. Calling requestFocusInWindow() on the JFileChooser might help, but I can't be certain.